# How to test redirection to Soundcloud with Rails/Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, soundcloud

I have a Rails application that redirects to Soundcloud so that the user can connect to his account. I am testing this process with Cucumber but i have several errors.

- Without another gem to handle the redirection, i get a timeout
- I tried using Capybara-mechanize.

  ```
  When /^I successfully connect to Soundcloud$/ do 
      Capybara.app_host = "https://soundcloud.com"
      steps %Q{
          When I follow "sc_connect"
          And I fill in the following:
          | username     |    myusername              |   
          | password     |    mypassword              |
          And I press "Connect"
      }
  end
  ```

I can actually see the redirection working but i am on the page '/logout', so Capybara cannot select and fill in the fields, and i get an error. Only then cucumber gets to the login page and stops.

I get this error :

**Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError (Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError)**

I would like to find a way to test these redirections properly using Cucumber.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to use selenium to test with cucumber outside the scope of the app. To do that, add a `@selenium` tag to your scenario.

Alternatively, if you just wanted to test the redirect you're better off doing that in a controller test.